# Where are NSUserDefaults stored on El Capitan?

Tags: nsuserdefaults

In my Mac XCode project I have a bundle identifier of "com.gargoylesoft.DTS-macOS".  I'm trying to blow away the stored defaults on this user so I did this:

`find ~ -name 'com.gargoylesoft.D*' -exec rm -rf {} \;`

When I then run the app, through Xcode, I'm still getting values from previous runs when I query `NSUserDefauls`.  Where in the world is it storing this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must never delete (or edit) preference files directly on macOS! macOS caches preferences using a background daemon named `cfprefsd`. The daemon won't notice that you delete (or alter) the files, it keeps a cached copy in RAM that it will only expire if your system gets memory pressure. Memory pressure means: an app needs RAM but no unused RAM is available, then the system signals memory pressure, causing all kind of system services to flush their caches as that is still better than swapping to disk (will also work in your own application, just try to always use `NSCache` when caching data, as it will automatically react to memory pressure).

If you want to delete prefs, use `defaults` in terminal, like this

```
# defaults delete com.gargoylesoft.DTS-macOS
```

This will delete the file and it will make sure that also `cfprefsd` flushes its caches for that file.

Another advantage of `defaults` is that you also don't need to know if an application is sandboxed or not, as a normal application stores its prefs in

```
~/Library/Preferences
```

whereas a sandoxed one stores them in

```
~/Library/Containers/BUNDLE_ID/Data/Library/Preferences/
```

but `defaults`will always look in the appropriate place.

Once you deleted a pref file by hand, you need to kill `cfprefsd` of your user (careful, there's one for your user and one for root - you don't want to kill the root one if these were user settings) and the system should then restart it for you. Or just reboot or at least log out and back in, both will restart it as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I've been having an issue where I use defaults write and it's not actually updating when the app runs.  The delete definitely worked though.  Thanks.